# Create a function that deletes word on point and replace with the yank register on Evil-emacs

Tags: key-bindings, evil

I want to emulate this vim remap in evil-emacs (doom emacs).

`nnoremap <leader>mpp ciw<C-r>0`

I want to change the word on point (I don't mind word or Word, just want the evil-change with evil-inner-word syntax). If possible I want it defined on an interactive function to remap it to leader mpp.

I want a remap that substitutes current word on point with yank/clipboard content.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this works as you want. Non-evil mode that I originally wrote for reference, as I'm not a day-to-day evil-mode user.

```
(defun replace-word-at-point ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((bounds (bounds-of-thing-at-point 'word)))
    (if bounds
      (progn (delete-and-extract-region (car-safe bounds) (cdr-safe bounds))
             (yank))
      (message "No word at point"))))

(defun replace-evil-word-at-point ()
  "Select the word at point, remove it, and yank the most recent killed text. "
  (interactive)
  (let ((bounds (evil-inner-word)))
    (if bounds
      (progn (delete-and-extract-region (pop bounds) (pop bounds))
             (yank))
      (message "No word at point"))))
```

For instance (bold = character at point in each example, just take my word that the space is a bold space in the last one):

| Original | Plain emacs | Evil version |
| --- | --- | --- |
| this is my test w**o**rd | this is my test Hello! | this is my test Hello! |
| this is my test **w**ord | this is my test Hello! | this is my test Hello! |
| this is my test word | this is my Hello! word | this is my testHello!word |

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you!